# sed regex not working

Tags: regex, sed

I am using the following command to eliminate the bold text.

```
sed 's/\-?[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}//g' countries.txt
```

countries.txt contains data in the following format:

> Canillo   **42.5833   1.6667**    6
>
> Encamp    **42.5333   1.6333**    6
>
> Ordino    **-42.6 -1.55** 6

When I run find/replace in Sublime with my above regex, all the geographical coordinates are eliminated. When I use sed to execute the same regex, it doesn't work.

Comment: `sed` needs to be told this is [extended GREP](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4a), because it defaults to 'simplest'.

Comment: Try `sed 's/-?[0-9]\{1,4\}\.[0-9]\{1,4\}//g' countries.txt`.

Comment: @Jongware I added the `-E` switch and it worked properly. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to [*The -r Extended Regular Expression argument*](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-12) section at *Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett*:

> Because the meaning of certain characters are different between the regular and extended expressions, you need a command line argument to enable sed to use the extension.
>   ...
>   Mac OS X and FreeBSD uses `-E` instead of `-r`.

So, on MacOS or FreeBSD you may use

```
sed -E 's/\-?[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}//g' countries.txt
```

And in other environments:

```
sed -r 's/\-?[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}//g' countries.txt
```